# How do I fix this Discord AccountType.BOT error? - JDA

Tags: java, discord

I am getting into coding Discord bots and this is my first bot.
Here's my code:

```java
import net.dv8tion.jda.JDABuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.AccountType;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDA;

import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;

import static net.dv8tion.jda.api.AccountType.*;

public class javaclass {

    public static JDA jda;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws LoginException {

        JDABuilder builder = new JDABuilder(BOT).setToken("thisIsAtoken").build();


    }
}
```

I am not that new to Java, I'm just getting this error and I can't figure out why.
Note: I've also tried `JDABuilder builder = new JDABuilder(AccountType.BOT).setToken("thisIsAtoken").build();`
but regardless intellij insists otherwise.

Thank you

edit: I made the code this `jda = new JDABuilder(new AccountType(BOT)).setToken` and I get this error `'AccountType()' has private access in 'net.dv8tion.jda.api.AccountType'`

Comment: Please include the error message and stacktrace you are getting.

Comment: I've never used JDA, but if I just take a quick look through the docs, I see 3 things: 1) [That JDABuilder constructor](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/JDABuilder.html#%3Cinit%3E(net.dv8tion.jda.api.AccountType)) is deprecated, or possibly non-existant depending on what version you are using, and 2) The [`build()`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/JDABuilder.html#build()) method throws a `LoginException` if the token is invalid, and I highly doubt "thisIsAToken" is a valid token (maybe you just switched it out for the question, I'm not sure)

Comment: ... 3) The full namespace for [JDABuilder](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/JDABuilder.html) in the documentation is `net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder`, but you've used `net.dv8tion.jda.JDABuilder`, which doesn't show up in the documentation.

Comment: Read the jda readme before using it.

Answer (score 2):

Following the [JDA documentation](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA), and with the recent version 4.2, you need a different approach to make a JDA instance.

You should use: `JDABuilder builder = JDABuilder.createDefault("thisIsAtoken").build();`